# Error Spyder Python + opencv 3

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I have installed Opencv 3.1.4 on Spyder Python 2.7, all running on Windows Vista 32bits.

My code is

```
import cv2

import sys

cascPath = "C:\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    print faces
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I have this error

```js
runfile('C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/tracking-video-fonctionnel.py', wdir='C:/Anaconda2/Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-3b1671aa3a09>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/tracking-video-fonctionnel.py', wdir='C:/Anaconda2/Scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/tracking-video-fonctionnel.py", line 20, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor
```

However, this code is running on an other computer with the same spyder and opencv but on Windows 7 64bits

I think the issue is on opencv because I can't import cv2.cv but I can import cv2

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, it's to install a 2.x version of opencv

Comment: version 3.1 should work. In your code I only see that the flags property that needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

cv2.cv does not exist in  opencv3.0 +.  You can replace it with an index: try this:

```
flags=3
```

Anyway, I doubt that's the main reason for the error showing. According to the error you posted it did not reach that line. I am suspecting something else. Probably the camera source/frames are faulty, the COLOR_ could not convert it. In other words the frames are not loaded correctly. Try using a better Camera or in a good light environment. Better yet try it out with an image instead of a video and see.